# How to collect samples in multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have files below

`file1.csv,file2.csv....`

I would like to extract samples from each csv file.

I tried

`f1=pd.read_csv(file1.csv)`

`f1.sample(2)`

`f1.append(f2)`

I tried to loop and append.

I guess some solutions are more faster.

How can I collect samples in multiple csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).sample(2) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# sample size
N = 10
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).sample(N) for f in file_list], ignore_index=True)
```