# How to collect sample from multiple csv file (2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I once asked question below.

[How to collect samples in multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324974/how-to-collect-samples-in-multiple-csv-files)

I would like to add index as file name

file1

```
0 1
2 3
```

file2

```
4 5
```

file3

```
6 7 
8 9
```

with `file.sample(1)`

```
file1 0 1
file2 4 5
file3 8 9
```

How can I add index as original file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.concat({f[:-4]: pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in glob('file*.csv')})

         0  1
file1 0  0  1
      1  2  3
file2 0  4  5
file3 0  6  7
      1  8  9
```